# C# DropDownList and Session[""]

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, drop-down-menu

Everyone.

I have a little issue with selecting value from the dropdown list.
When user enters his/her credentials and selects the datasource name, they are all stored in session. When the user comes back to the login page later, I want him/her to see last selected datasource name.
It works for the first time, but when I try to change the datasource name, it doesnt change but the value chosen before appears. Can you help me with this issue?
Thanks!

default.aspx

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    private dbConnection connection = new dbConnection();
    private string[,] errorMessage = 
        { {"Expired", "Unsuccessful", "Incorrect"}, 
        {"Your Logon Session Has Expired", "Invalid Username or Password", 
            "Selected Data Source is not supported within this application"} };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ddlDatabase.DataTextField = "Value";
        ddlDatabase.DataValueField = "Key"; 
        ddlDatabase.DataSource = dbList.GetDbList();
        ddlDatabase.DataBind();    

        Response.Buffer = true;

        if (Session["Error"] != null)
                ErrorMessage();

        if (Session["Datasource"] != null)
            ddlDatabase.SelectedValue = Session["Datasource"].ToString();
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dataSource = ddlDatabase.SelectedValue;
        string userID = txtUserID.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;

        connection = new dbConnection(dataSource, userID, password);

        if (connection.IsValid())
        {
            try
            {
                connection.GetConnection().Open();
                Session["Username"] = userID;
                Session["Password"] = password;
                Session["Datasource"] = ddlDatabase.SelectedValue;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Redirect("main.aspx", false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblSessionInfo.Text = ex.Message;
                Session["Username"] = null;
                Session["Password"] = null;
                Session["Error"] = "Unsuccessful";
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Session["Username"] = null;
            Session["Password"] = null;
            Session["Datasource"] = null;
            Session["Error"] = "Incorrect";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        }
    }

    protected void ErrorMessage()
    {
        int length = errorMessage.Length / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            if (Session["Error"].ToString() == errorMessage[0, i])
                lblSessionInfo.Text = errorMessage[1, i];
    }
}
```

main.aspx (Logout)

```
public partial class main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    dbConnection connection = new dbConnection();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Buffer = true;
        if (Session["Username"] == null)
        {
            Session["Error"] = "Expired";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["Error"] = null;
        }

        Label1.Text = Session["Datasource"].ToString();
    }
    protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.GetConnection().Close();
        Session["Username"] = null;
        Session["Password"] = null;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString(), true); 
    }
}
```

dbList.cs

```
public class dbList
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> GetDbList()
    {
        //List<string> dataSources = new List<string>();
        var dataSources = new Dictionary<int, string>(); 

        RegistryKey reg = (Registry.LocalMachine).OpenSubKey("Software");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC.INI");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC Data Sources");

        if (reg != null)
        {
            string[] items = reg.GetValueNames();
            Array.Sort(items);
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string item in items)
            {
                dataSources.Add(i, item);
                i++;
            }
        }

        reg.Close();

        return dataSources;
    }
}
```

dbConnection.cs

```
public class dbConnection
{
    private string[] dataSources = { "name1", "name2", "name3" };

    public dbConnection() {}

    public dbConnection(string dataSource, string userID, string password)
    {
        DataSource = dataSource;
        UserID = userID;
        Password = password;
    }

    public string DataSource { get; set; }
    private string UserID { get; set; }
    private string Password { get; set; }

    public OracleConnection GetConnection()
    {
        OracleConnection connection = null;

        string connectionString = 
            @"Data Source="+ DataSource + 
            ";User ID=" + UserID + 
            ";Password=" + Password + 
            ";Unicode=True";

        try
        {
            connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }

        return connection;
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        int trueCount = 0;

        foreach (string dataSource in dataSources)
            if (DataSource == dataSource) trueCount++;

        if (trueCount > 0) return true;
        else  return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your logout code.  Perhaps you're clearing the session when the user clicks the logout button.

Comment: `but when I try to change the datasource name` how do you change the it? can you post the code relating to that?

Comment: @Bala R, What I meant was "When I select a new datasource from the list". When I do that, the value that was stored in Session["Datasource"] in a first place is used. It simply does not overwrite session value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution. It is much simpler than I thought.
Instead of using `ddlDatabase.DataSource`, I used `ddlDatabase.Items.Add();` and added `Session["Datasource"] = null;`. Here are the codes:

**default.aspx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    private db connection = new db();
    private string[,] errorMessage = 
        { {"Expired", "Unsuccessful", "Incorrect"}, 
        {"Your Logon Session Has Expired", "Invalid Username or Password", 
            "Selected Data Source is not supported within this application"} };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Buffer = true;

        foreach (string name in connection.GetDbList())
            ddlDatabase.Items.Add(name);

        if (Session["Error"] != null)
                ErrorMessage();

        if (Session["Datasource"] != null)
        {
            ddlDatabase.SelectedValue = Session["Datasource"].ToString();
            Session["Datasource"] = null;
        }

    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dataSource = ddlDatabase.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string userID = txtUserID.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;

        connection = new db(dataSource, userID, password);

        if (connection.IsValid())
        {
            try
            {
                connection.GetConnection().Open();
                Session["Username"] = userID;
                Session["Password"] = password;
                Session["Datasource"] = ddlDatabase.SelectedValue;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Redirect("main.aspx", false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblSessionInfo.Text = ex.Message;
                Session["Username"] = null;
                Session["Password"] = null;
                Session["Datasource"] = ddlDatabase.SelectedValue;
                Session["Error"] = "Unsuccessful";
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Session["Username"] = null;
            Session["Password"] = null;
            Session["Datasource"] = null;
            Session["Error"] = "Incorrect";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        }
    }

    protected void ErrorMessage()
    {
        int length = errorMessage.Length / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            if (Session["Error"].ToString() == errorMessage[0, i])
                lblSessionInfo.Text = errorMessage[1, i];
    }
}
```

**db.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public class db
{
    private string[] dataSources = { "ValidNames" };

    public db() {}

    public db(string dataSource, string userID, string password)
    {
        DataSource = dataSource;
        UserID = userID;
        Password = password;
    }

    private string DataSource { get; set; }
    private string UserID { get; set; }
    private string Password { get; set; }

    public OracleConnection GetConnection()
    {
        OracleConnection connection = null;

        string connectionString = 
            @"Data Source="+ DataSource + 
            ";User ID=" + UserID + 
            ";Password=" + Password + 
            ";Unicode=True";

        try
        {
            connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }

        return connection;
    }

    public List<string> GetDbList()
    {
        List<string> dataSources = new List<string>();

        RegistryKey reg = (Registry.LocalMachine).OpenSubKey("Software");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC.INI");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC Data Sources");

        if (reg != null)
        {
            string[] items = reg.GetValueNames();
            Array.Sort(items);
            foreach (string item in items)
                dataSources.Add(item);
        }

        reg.Close();

        return dataSources;
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        int trueCount = 0;

        foreach (string dataSource in dataSources)
            if (DataSource == dataSource) trueCount++;

        if (trueCount > 0) return true;
        else  return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE: 6/13/2011

Can you try creating a `Dictionary` instead of a `List<string>` in your get `GetConnection()` method?

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(1, "Connection1");
dictionary.Add(2, "Connection2");
dictionary.Add(3, "Connection3");
dictionary.Add(4, "Connection4");

// Binding the dictionary to the DropDownList:
dropDown.DataTextField = "Value";
dropDown.DataValueField = "Key";
dropDown.DataSource = dictionary;  //Dictionary<int, string>
dropDown.DataBind();
```

---

You need to Bind Your 'ddlDatabase' First & then set the SelectedValue. Otherwise, only 1 item is created (with the SelectedValue) in yourDropdown list, and you dont have any items to choose from Except the one item.

```
//Code to databind ddlDatabase
BindDatabaseDropdown();
if (Session["Datasource"] != null)
        ddlDatabase.SelectedValue = Session["Datasource"].ToString();
```

Comment: Is BindDatabaseDropdown(); a method that I am suppoesd to write?

Comment: i meant you should perhabs have your Dropdown Databinding Code there. If you are Using "GetDbList()" method to get the Dropdown Items, you might want to have ddlDatabase.DataSource = GetDBList(); ddlDatabase.DataBind();

Comment: I try and use ddlDatabase.DataBind(); but it always selects the very first value...

Comment: btw, when & how are you binding your DropdownList? can you post the Databinding code?

Comment: you need to have if (Session["Datasource"] != null)
        ddlDatabase.SelectedValue = Session["Datasource"].ToString(); after Databinding, so proper item is selected.

Comment: Previously, I set the datasource in Visual studio "Design" editor. Now I tryed to use ddlDatabase.DataSource = GetDBList(); ddlDatabase.DataBind(); but it always selects the firs value..

Comment: did you try my above comment? setting SelectedValue after databinding?

Comment: yeah, that's what I was trying to do

Comment: to clarify, the first item is selected on page load, so when I push Login button, that first item is used.

Comment: not yet, unless we can see the whole code. Can you modify your post to include the whole code (codebehind) for Login & Logout Pages?

Comment: For some reason it wouldn't select another value rather that the one set on the page load. Even if I set value manually, it will be selected on page load and no other value could be selected

Comment: ive updated the answer. can you try using Dictionary instead of List<string> ?

Comment: Did you mean the 'GetDbList()' method, not 'GetConnection()'?

Comment: can you put dropDown.DataTextField = "Value";
dropDown.DataValueField = "Key"; before dropDown.DataBind()?

Comment: I did that, sorry, didn't include that in the code.. Still the same

Comment: last resort, can you just check if your session value  Debug.WriteLine(Session["Datasource"].ToString()); exists in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Value doesn't exist until the right database is chosen. Before then it is null. And it doesn't really matter yet which value is in Session. DDL's selected value daes not change when I select a new value, it remains the same as page loads

Comment: ok, makes sense. Does your Dropdownlist posts back(AutoPostback = true)? if it doesnt, try binding the GridView  only when Not Postback (if !isPostBack).

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it simply because of that part of the code ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlDatabase.DataSource = dbList.GetDbList();
    ddlDatabase.DataBind();

    Response.Buffer = true;

    if (Session["Error"] != null)
            ErrorMessage();

    if (Session["Datasource"] != null)
        ddlDatabase.SelectedValue = Session["Datasource"].ToString();
}
```

The `ddlDatabase.SelectedValue = Session["Datasource"].ToString();` should be called only on first page load (`if(!isPostBack)`). The way it is now, the selected value in your drop down list would always (ALWAYS) be taken from the session, before the Click_handler is called. Therefore, in that part :

```
Session["Password"] = password;
Session["Datasource"] = ddlDatabase.SelectedValue;
Response.Clear();
```

the `ddlDatabase.SelectedValue` is no longer the value the user selected...